# Is it possible to read the original internal stylesheet rules via jQuery after they have been changed with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I feel a bit ridiculous even asking, but some of the research I have done makes me think that it might be possible?

Say I have an internal CSS rule like this:

```
<style>div {width 50px;}</style>
```

And then I use jQuery to change the value of the width of the div like this:

```
$('div').css({"width":"100px"});
```

Is it possible to retrieve the original width of 50px from the original CSS rules using JavaScript?

Or is the only way to first save the original width value of 50px in a  javascript variable and retrieve it later using that same variable?

In theory... the original values are all still contained and accessible via the source code of the page... and I don't really care to go that far (to write a CSS parser in javascript).

Or does the source of the page cease to exist basically when the browser renders the DOM?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: You can find the original CSS in `document.styleSheets`. But figuring out which rules apply to a particular element would be hard work.

Comment: You could temporarily remove the added CSS, get the width, then add it back.

Comment: @ScottMarcus The OP misused the term, he's asking about `<style>` blocks.

Comment: *"Say I have an inlined CSS rule like this: <style>div {width 50px;}</style>"*. That's not an "inlined" rule. That's an "internal style sheet". An inline style is like this `<p style='color:blue'>`

Comment: As with any programming element that holds a value, that value is lost when another takes its place. All you can do is record the original value before it changes so that you can restore it later.

Comment: *"In theory... the original values are all still contained and accessible via the source code of the page."* No, the original values are stored within the source code of the file served to the browser. The source code of the page is what's rendered in the browser (also known as the DOM) and that will change as often as it is instructed to.

Comment: @Barmar regarding document.styleSheets ... yes! That is exactly what kept coming up in my research, but it seemed very obtuse. I'll keep researching that approach for now. Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 0):

Not possible as far as I know. As Barmar said, easiest way would be to remove the style, get the original value, then add the style again.

Something like this should work:

```
function getOriginalCSS(target,styles){
    var output = {}
    for(var i=0; i<styles.length; i++){
        var style = styles[i]
        var current = target.css(style)
        target.css(style,'')
        output[style] = target.css(style)
        target.css(style,current)
    }
    return output
}
```

Calling `getOriginalCSS($('div'),['width'])` should give you `{width:'50px'}`

Comment: That is a great solution! I'm going to try it out now! Sorry I cannot upvote you because my account is too new apparently.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to save the previous value before you change the CSS and then re-apply the old value when you need.

Any other way would be tedious and frankly not worth the work-around.